# Почему периодически крашется приложение на Android?

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity, xamarin, monodroid

Периодически крашется приложение на Android. При чем каждый раз в разных местах. Не могу понять по какой причине. Структура приложения простая: имеется одна **Activity** и куча **фрагментов**. Вывод фрагмента осуществляется так:

```
ItemsFragment itemsFragment = new ItemsFragment() { GroupID = groupID, CurrentGroup = currentGroup };
itemsFragment.RetainInstance = true; 
var fragmentManager = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
fragmentManager.Replace(Resource.Id.flContent, (SupportFragment)itemsFragment);
fragmentManager.AddToBackStack(null);
fragmentManager.Commit();
```

Использую C# Xamarin, но на java принцип тотже, только синтаксис немного другой.
Помогите новичку android-разработчику понять и разобраться в чем причина.

Comment: Информация об ошибках имеется? Текст, номер или что-нибудь?

Comment: На мобильном устройстве вылетает с ошибкой:“Unfortunately App has Stopped”

Comment: Где только можно натыкал попыток и получил такую ошибку: Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Comment: Ну вот, теперь с текстом ошибки сначала в гугл и изучайте топ 3 результата.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю на счет C#, но в Jave такой метод есть, попробуй заменить последнюю строку на :

```
fragmentManager.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую...